# Two horses can pull three time as much one horse. Is this only true for horses?

Tags: pack-animals

I was looking up how much horses,ox,mules and donkeys  can pull and read that 2 horses can pull 3 times as much as 1 horse

What about ox,mules and donkeys? Does a pair of ox or mules or donkeys pull 3 times as much as 1 can or is it double of what one can pull?

Comment: source, and how is it measured? (Also, relevance?)

Comment: This source [Horse Sense](https://timmaurer.com/2012/01/16/horse-sense/) states it but claims the reason is *team work*. It's not an animal site but about money. Here is another site: [How much weight can a horse pull?](https://horserookie.com/how-much-weight-can-a-horse-pull/)

Comment: This isn't really about the Great Outdoors as per our site scope. It's really a physics question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is about carts and not ploughs (plows), this is because the 'rolling resistance' is not proportional to load. If half of one horse's efforts are to overcome rolling resistance and friction, with half pulling the load, then the second horse's effort is entirely pulling the load: 3 times the pulling power.

The same applies to oxen and internal combustion engines too. If a 100cc engine will just about pull a vehicle, then the 200cc engine will have a lot of acceleration.